# WebSphere 8.5.5 EAR's topology

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, cluster-computing, ear

I'm planning best topology for my project. What I need is an ability to have EAR running on part of cluster members, while other cluster members are running different EAR. 
Is such topology is possibly on WebSphere 8.5.5 ?
Thanks !

Comment: yes. /morechars

Answer (score 1):

In the context of WebSphere Application Server, clusters are sets of servers that provide workload management. All servers that are part of the same cluster must have identical application components deployed on them. Other than the applications, the members do not have to share any configuration data.

To have multiple applications running on multiple servers, you can always define additional clusters.

Additional info:

- [Introduction to Clusters](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/welcclusters.html)
- [Clusters and workload management](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/crun_srvgrp.html)